# Prove convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(1-q)\cdot{n}\cdot{q^{n-1}}}$ for $q\in{-1,1}$ and find the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

The initial question is prove convergence and find limit for  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n\cdot{q^{n-1}}}$ for $q\in{(-1,1)}$ but we are given the hint to use: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(1-q)\cdot{n}\cdot{q^{n-1}}}$ for $q\in{(-1,1)}$. I thought it would be easier to consider absolute convergence because it makes the problem slightly simpler. After that I do not know how one proves this nor find the limit.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(1-q)\cdot{n}\cdot{q^{n-1}}}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m{(1-q)\cdot{n}\cdot{q^{n-1}}}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{q^m(1+m-mq)-1}{q-1}=\frac{1}{q-1}\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(q^m(1+m-mq)-1\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{q-1}\left(0-1\right)=-\frac{1}{q-1}=\frac{1}{1-q}\space\space\text{when}\space|q|<1$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n=\frac 1{1-q},\quad\text{for }q\in(-1,1)$$
then take the derivative of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-q)\,n\,q^{n-1}
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(1-q)\,n\,q^{n-1}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^Nn\,q^{n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^Nn\,q^n\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(n+1)\,q^n-\sum_{n=1}^Nn\,q^n\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}q^n-Nq^N\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} q^n\\
\end{align}
$$
Multiply by $\frac{1-q}{1-q}$ and try the same approach: split the sum and evaluate the [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).